# Copy date from one line to multiple lines (Regex Notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've been using Notepad++ for a while now but I haven't been able to figure this one out so any help is appreciated. I have this:

> Day:2016-08-06
>
> DATE/1850_01.xlsx
>
> DATE/1850_02.xlsx
>
> DATE/1850_03.xlsx
>
> DATE/1850_04.xlsx
>
> DATE/1850_05.xlsx
>
> DATE/1850_06.xlsx
>
> DATE/1850_07.xlsx
>
> DATE/1850_08.xlsx

And I need a regex that takes the date in "Day:" (which here is 2016-08-06 but it varies, may be another random date like 2016-04-23 and so on) and replaces it on all of the "DATE". Basically this:

> Day:2016-08-06
>
> 2016-08-06/1850_01.xlsx
>
> 2016-08-06/1850_02.xlsx
>
> 2016-08-06/1850_03.xlsx
>
> 2016-08-06/1850_04.xlsx
>
> 2016-08-06/1850_05.xlsx
>
> 2016-08-06/1850_06.xlsx
>
> 2016-08-06/1850_07.xlsx
>
> 2016-08-06/1850_08.xlsx

Comment: Is there only a single `Day` entry, or would there many of these all in the same file?

Comment: Best is to write a Python script for this if you need full one click automation. A regex can be written but you will have to click Replace all several times until no match is found. The difficulty is that you need to capture some text before another and use it several times inside a block.

Comment: Only one single Day entry per file. And about the python script, I've never really tried doing anything with python but I wouldn't be opposed in trying something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Here is a a regular expression find/replace approach:

   - Open Replace Dialog
   - **Find What:** `(Day:([^[:space:]]+).*?)DATE`
   - **Replace With:** `\1\2`
   - check **regular expression**
   - check **`. mathces newline`**
   - click Replace or Replace All

   This will replace the first occurence. You have to repeat `Replace` until all replacements are done (Replace All does not make a difference due to the nature of the RE). You can keep Alt-R pressed in the replace dialog, it is fast.
2. But there is another approach: Mark the date, copy it into clipboard, use a normal Replace, to replace `DATE` with the copied date from the first line, here Replace all will work. Its about the same keypresses and it is more straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I figured it out now.